# How to achieve very slight text shadows in CSS?

Tags: css

property in CSS is a good way to have shadows for dynamic text in HTML. However the browsers (especially safari, firefox) render a quite strong shadow with quite low settings:

```
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000; // still quite strong
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000; // still quite strong
text-shadow:0.01em 0.01em 0.01em #000; // some browsers do not even display this
```

How can I achieve cross browsers-compatible text shadows which are still not as strong as the first two given text shadows, but still displayed? Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a "weaker" colour:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
```

Adjust that `0.25` as needed - a value of `0` will be invisible, and `1` will be the same as the `#000` you're currently using.

Comment: Both answers correct, as Oriol was first you get an upvote instead for explaining it in more detail.

Comment: Actually, I was first - My answer was posted at 15:36:05, whereas Oriol's was 15:37:39 ;)

Comment: Ok I see - so now I know that early answers are at the bottom and lets do it the other way round O:-)

Comment: It all depends on how you have the answers sorted - you probably have the "active" tab selected? That'd exaplain it :) In future, just mouse over the "answered yesterday" and you can see the exact time ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You could try semi-transparent `text-shadow`:

```
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t55Zk/1/)